# Issues working with JSF redirect and WebTrends

Tags: jsp, jsf, webtrends

On our new platform we are utilizing JSF.  Our WebTrends tags are not reflecting the proper page title on this platform.  It currently is displaying the name of the users previous page instead of the current page.

We are making use of the JSF Navigation rule in which we have some "< redirect />" tags.

Has anyone experienced this and is there a solution.  I have made the suggestion that we move a way from this model, still use JSF but not the navigation rules.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved this problem by using the webtrends javascript API to inject the correct page title into the page (instead of relying on the javascript to read the correct URL from the page). Since JSF mucks with your URLs, there really isn't much else you can do.

The redirect tags will work, but you have to watch your managed bean's logic, since it breaks request scope.